# the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ converges uniformly Choose the correct option

Tags: real-analysis

let  $f :\mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ be  non zero function such that $|f(x)| \le \frac{1}{1+2x^2}$  for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ .Define real value  function $f_n$  on $\mathbb{R}$  for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by $f_n(x) = f(x +n)$.

Then ,the series  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$  converges  uniformly

Choose the correct option

$a)$ on $[0,1]$

$b)$ on $[-1,0]$

$c)$ on $[-1,1]$

$d)$  None of these

I thinks  option $a) ,b)$ and $c)$  will correct  because derivative of $f$  is  bounded

Is its  True??

Comment: See $\displaystyle f_n<\dfrac{1}{1+2x^2} \:\forall\:n$. So what can you say about the sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

We are not given that $f$ is differentiable.

So, note that for $x\in [-1,1]$

$$|f_n(x)|=|f(x+n)|\le \frac{1}{1+2(x+n)^2}\le \frac1{1+2(n-1)^2}$$

Appeal to the Weierstrass M-Test.  Can you finish?